# A moving set of synchronized clocks

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

Lorentz's formula relating the time $t$ in reference frame $S$ to the time $t'$ in the reference frame $S'$, which is moving with velocity $v$ (along the $x$ axis of $S$) with respect to $S$, reads

$$t'=\gamma \bigg ( t-\frac{vx}{c^2}\bigg ).$$

Suppose we have a set of synchronized clocks along the $x'$ axis $S'$. At a specified time $t=t_{0}$, we measure the time readings of these moving clocks in $S$. We find that the readings vary as a linear function of $x$ according to

$$t'=\gamma \bigg ( t_{0}-\frac{vx}{c^2}\bigg ).$$

So at $t_{0}$, the clocks, as viewed in $S$, are not synchronized. But we assumed that the clocks were synchronized in $S'$. And the clocks can only be either synchronized or not synchronized, not both. So where does this contradiction come from?

Answer (score 2):

The clocks are synchronised in the S' frame but not the S frame. This is not a contradiction.

You have to deconstruct 'synchronisation'.  If two clocks, one near an observer  and one far away, are synchronised this does *not* mean that the observer sees them indicating the same time, because of the time the image of the clock takes to reach them. If the far clock is 1000m away then, if it is synchronised with the near clock, it would show a time 3.333 microseconds behind.

Another observer in another frame (but, coincidentally, at the same space-time point as the first observer) would agree as to what the two clocks showed,  but they would not agree about the 1000 m, and so would say that the clocks were not synchronised.

It's all part of the relativity of simultaneity

Comment: "The clocks are synchronized in the S' frame but not the S frame". Let us say we have digital clocks. So what this is saying is in S' the clocks are all showing the same numbers on their screens,whereas in S each is showing a different number. But the clocks must be either all showing the same time, or desynchronized, without any reference to an observer.

Comment: Read my answer. "Showing" kind of implies an observer. And that's correct.  According to Einstein, space and time cannot be used without asking 'how would you measure this...'.  Synchronisation has no absolute meaning but needs an observer and - surprisingly - turns out to depend on the observer.

Comment: @Hilbert You may find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity helpful, especially the diagrams near the start of the article. I'm especially fond of [the animated one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/78/Relativity_of_Simultaneity_Animation.gif)